# Memory Allocation of variables & constants outside Swift classes

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I've seen code examples of variables and constants created outside classes as a way to avoid hard-coding.
Are they a good practice in terms of memory allocation?
For example:

```
private let cellId = "myCellId"

class ViewController : UIViewController {

    ...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)
    ...
}
```

When are these constants/variables allocated/deallocated in an iOS application?

Comment: Abizern answered the first question. Re when they're deallocated, the answer is that they are never deallocated. So you might only want to use this construct where (a) the object being allocated isn't too big (i.e. you don't mind keeping it around even when the object that needed it is no longer around); and (b) you're likely to need it again later.

Answer (score 3):

Top level global variables like this are lazily initialised. Also, they are implicitly allocated within a `dispatch_once` so they are thread safe.

> The lazy initializer for a global variable (also for static members of structs and enums) is run the first time that global is accessed, and is launched as dispatch_once to make sure that the initialization is atomic. This enables a cool way to use dispatch_once in your code: just declare a global variable with an initializer and mark it private.

Reference: [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7)

Answer (score 3):

In general, Abizern is correct. However, constant strings are a bit of special case. They're never allocated. They live in your binary image, which is memory mapped, which is about as close to "free" as you can get. Since structs are exactly their contents (i.e. there's no header on a struct), your string costs exactly 9 bytes in the binary (the characters plus a trailing 0). It is never allocated; it just is.

Since `cellId` is `let`, the compiler can replace references to it with the actual memory location in the binary that holds the data. There's not even a need for a pointer for `cellId` itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That would mean that I could pretty well use this technique for Strings and Numbers (and other value types) to soft-code constants throughout my class files? 
Would you have any reference or blog post elaborating this? Thanks again!

Comment: Not all value types; but at least strings and numbers; some others might be special-cased as well. The compiler needs to know how to construct them at compile time. I'm not sure how this is documented. It's not a language requirement of Swift; it's just how it's implemented, and is based on how C compilers have done this for decades. Kind of like how if you write "x = 1 + 2" every compiler in any modern compiled language is going to store "x = 3", but I don't know any language specification that requires it.

Comment: Right, that makes sense! I thought perhaps this could apply to constants of the Core Graphics framework as well such as `CGFloat` and even struct types like `CGRect` since they're composed of simple numeric data types.